# Gave my boss two weeks notice. Should I tell my coworkers?

Tags: professionalism, resignation

I gave my boss two weeks notice a few days ago, but I haven't told any of my coworkers (and they don't seem to know, either). I'm still receiving invites for meetings and assigned tasks with due dates passed my last day.

I have full intentions to get my current projects as close to complete as possible given the time, but there's no possibility of me starting on new things that have been assigned to me and certainly no possibility of me sitting in a meeting two weeks after I've left.

What obligations, if any, do I have to discuss my leaving with coworkers?

Comment: Talk to your boss how to handle it and let him schedule your last 2 weeks

Comment: What your boss should have  you do is transition unfinished projects to someone else while you have time to explain things.